# How to solve this Python AssertionError: "Unable to find definition for "distance"?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, assertion

I am doing distance code and when I am testing it, it raises *Traceback (most recent call last): File "/tmp/autograde_akr470nh/week2_tests.py", line 22, in test_distance result = self.submission.distance(x, y) File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/grader-0.0.1-py3.7.egg/grader/testing.py", line 32, in getattr raise AssertionError('Unable to find definition for "%s"' % name) AssertionError: Unable to find definition for "distance"*.

Here is my distance code:

```
def distance(x0, x1):
    distance = np.sqrt((x0-x1).T @ (x0-x1))
    return distance
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example so we can reproduce your error. My guess is (a) you are not executing the block that has defined the function. Otherwise (b) it might be related to the fact that you have both a variable and a function with the same name (`distance`). Try renaming one of them.

Comment: What is the full traceback of the Assertion error?  What is the code in and proceeding the lines raising the AssertionError?

Comment: I've executed or maybe because of both variable and function has the same name, i will try change it

Comment: @nigh_anxiety here's the full traceback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/autograde_akr470nh/week2_tests.py", line 22, in test_distance
    result = self.submission.distance(x, y)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/grader-0.0.1-py3.7.egg/grader/testing.py", line 32, in __getattr__
    raise AssertionError('Unable to find definition for \"%s\"' % name)
AssertionError: Unable to find definition for "distance"

Comment: The Traceback should be added to the question content, not as a comment.  That being said, I have more follow up questions - it looks like possibly running automated tests, and its the automated tests that are failing, and it appears to be because your code is not structured correctly for it to be able to find your distance method.  Is this a school assignment or for some coding website?  Can you provide more of (or the entirety of) your script?

Comment: @nigh_anxiety this is for course assignment on coursera

Comment: @NilaMaula Then can you show your entire submission?  It sounds you may have it incorrectly structured, as the auto-grader is looking for `distance` as a method of `submission` and can't find it there.

Comment: @nigh_anxiety solved, it turns out that i have to upload the assignment manually

Answer (score 0):

Try renaming local variable **distance** to **result** or something diffrent, is shadowing the name of the function "distance".

```
result = np.sqrt((x0-x1).T @ (x0-x1))
return result
```

or simply

```
return np.sqrt((x0-x1).T @ (x0-x1))
```